# How to debug TVHeadend "scan no data, failed"

Tags: television, dvb

I have compiled the driver for my Geniatech T230C DVB-T2 USB receiver according to https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Geniatech_T230C and it seems to work.
But when I try to scan for channels with TVHeadend 4.0.8 on my Raspbian Jessie system TVHeadend reports:

```
:
2017-04-06 02:22:34.000 mpegts: 706MHz in DVB-T2 - scan no data, failed
2017-04-06 02:22:34.000 subscription: 01FC: "scan" unsubscribing
2017-04-06 02:22:44.000 mpegts: 546MHz in DVB-T2 - tuning on Silicon Labs Si2168 : DVB-T #0
2017-04-06 02:22:44.000 subscription: 01FE: "scan" subscribing to mux "546MHz", weight: 2, adapter: "Silicon Labs Si2168 : DVB-T #0", network: "DVB-T2", service: "Raw PID Subscription" comet failure [e=this.el.dom is undefined]
2017-04-06 02:22:49.000 mpegts: 546MHz in DVB-T2 - scan no data, failed
2017-04-06 02:22:49.000 subscription: 01FE: "scan" unsubscribing
:
```

Only 3 SD channels but no HD channels are found.
With http://www.dvbviewer.com/de/ I could receive all HD Channels in good quality on Windows 10.

What could be the problem?

Could the version of TVHeadend be too old?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to perform a re-scan by shutting down tvheadend (on debian/ubuntu `service tvheadend stop`), removing the usb tuner, counting to 10 :-), inserting the tuner, starting tvheadend and tailed syslog until it had finished scanning.
After that, I had to go back into the UI and selecting `configuration | DVB Inputs | Services | Map Services -> Map All Services`.
I then had all my services back (in their new positions). Just a matter then of deleting all the porn and sales channels :-)

Comment: by 'deleting' I mean un-ticking the 'enabled' box in the channel viewer.  I also disabled the channels that were not mapped correctly.  I had to wait until after 7pm to do a re-map as I realised that BBC 4 wasn't in the list (it doesn't start until 7pm.)